# Java Reflection without qualified name

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to do Java Reflection using `Class c = Class.forName(className)`

I want to pass in the `className` without specifying the package name as the String `className` will contain classes from multiple sub-packages say `com.A.*`,`com.B.*` .... `com.Z.*`

Is it possible?

It will not be feasible to do a case switch to pre-pend the different sub-packages if I have many sub-packages in this case.

Comment: className can only contain a single fully qualified class. It cannot end in a `*`. I might be misinterpreting your intention, could you elaborate with some examples?

Comment: @HieryNomus i'm not ending it with `*`. Jus having classes to reflect from **different** sub-packages.

Comment: It's not possible, but how would you even define its semantics? For instance, what would `Class.forName("Date")` do? (There are two classes in the JDK whose simple name is "Date.")

Comment: Because the `className` will be classes coming from within my own package. And I will not have same class name from different sub package of my.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, get all classes with the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections();

 Set<Class<?>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

Next, build up a lookup-map.

```
// Doesn't handle collisions (you might want to use a multimap such as http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html instead)
Map<String, Class<?>> classBySimpleName = new HashMap<>();

for(Class<?> c : allClasses) {
    classBySimpleName.put(c.getSimpleName(), c);         
}
```

When you need to lookup a class you'll do:

```
Class<?> clazz = classBySimpleName.get(className);
```

Comment: Don't you think you are unnecessarily instantiating classes that aren't required?

Comment: Watch out for collisions. `classBySimpleName.get("List")` randomly returns `java.util.List` or `javax.swing.List`

Answer (score 11):

One simple option would be to have a list of *candidate* packages:

```
for (String pkg : packages) {
    String fullyQualified = pkg + "." + className;
    try {
        return Class.forName(fullyQualified);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Oops. Try again with the next package
    }
}
```

This won't be the *nicest* code in the world, admittedly...

You *may* be able to make it faster by looking for alternative calls (e.g. `ClassLoader.getResource`) which don't throw exceptions if the class isn't found.

There's certainly nothing I'm aware of to allow you to find a class *without* specifying a name at all.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc of java.lang.Class its not possible

```
public static Class<?> forName(String className)
                    throws ClassNotFoundException

Parameters:
className - the fully qualified name of the desired class.
Returns:
the Class object for the class with the specified name.
```