# Search for a specific class and return it

Tags: java, class, casting

I'm having a function that returns (in my case) a `Block`.
I am having a string named `blockName` which value will be set to "dirt".
After that I'm creating a new string named `blockNameConverted`. This will be `BlockDirt` and I also have a class `BlockDirt` (it's not in the same package):

```
public Block getBlockFromId(int id){

    String blockName = iBlockRegistry.getStrintFromId(id).getStringValue(); // Yeah i know.. it's Strint :D
    String blockNameConverted = "Block" + blockName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + blockName.substring(1); //Capitalize the d of dirt

    debug.Log("Blockname: " + blockName);  //Outputs in Console "Blockname: dirt"
    debug.Log("Converted Blockname: " + blockNameConverted); //Outputs in Console "Converted Blockname: BlockDirt"

    Class<?> clas;
    try {
        clas = Class.forName(blockNameConverted);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        clas = BlockDirt.class.getClass(); //If class not found use this class as "default"
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Block blockClass = Block.class.cast(clas);

    return blockClass;
}
```

I think `clas = Class.forName(blockNameConverted);` should search for the class `BlockDirt` but when i call this method i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BlockDirt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at registry.MinecraftRegistry.getBlockFromId(MinecraftRegistry.java:39)
    at registry.BlockRegistry.register(BlockRegistry.java:11)
    at block.Block.registerBlock(Block.java:21)
    at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:126)
```

and also this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Class to block.Block
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    at registry.MinecraftRegistry.getBlockFromId(MinecraftRegistry.java:44)
    at registry.BlockRegistry.register(BlockRegistry.java:11)
    at block.Block.registerBlock(Block.java:21)
    at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:126)
```

What am i doing wrong?

I have not posted my complete class because i just want to know how to search for a class and return (or use) it.

With `Block blockClass = Block.class.cast(clas);` i want to get like the same result as `Block blockClass = new BlockDirt();` but i cant type this directly in my code because later i also want to create other blocks and dont want to get every time the id of `BlockDirt`.

I hope you can understand me because english is not my mother language :D

Comment: You are casting _the class itself_ to a Block. It is not a Block. Create a new instance of the class using `clas.newInstance()`.

Comment: And the first exception simply means: the class BlockDirt is **not** in the class path of the JVM that runs your code.

Comment: Two different errors, two separate problems: 1) `ClassNotFoundException`: your classpath is wrong, and/or you're not specifying the correct class name, 2) `ClassCastException`: you must cast a *CLASS INSTANCE OF BLOCK*, not a "Class" object"

Comment: You should probably use `BlockDirt` with its full name: `com.test.BlockDirt` for `Class.forName`

Comment: `Class clazz = Class.forName("com.test.BlockDirt");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BlockDirt`

Your first exception tells you the class `BlockDirt` does not exist on the classpath. You need the right package name as well. Example:

```
Class.forName("foo.bar.someprogram.BlockDirt");
```

In your case something like this would probably be what you need.

```
Class<? extends Block> myClass = Class.forName(myPackageName + blockNameConverted);
```

---

> `Cannot cast java.lang.Class to block.Block`

You are casting *the class itself* to a `Block`. It is not a `Block`. Only an *instance* of `Block` can be cast to `Block`. Create a new instance of the class using `myClass.newInstance()`. Keep in mind that the class's constructor must have no arguments for this method to work properly. If you want to use a multi-argument constructor you can do `myClass.getConstructor(someParameters).newInstance(someArguments)`.

Example:

Say your class has a constructor with the signature `BlockDirt(String name, int someNumber)`.

To create a new instance using this constructor with reflection, do:

```
Block block = myClass.getConstructor(String.class, int.class).newInstance("Foo", 42);
```

---

Keep in mind you *need* the package name for reflection to work. If you know what packages it *might* be in, you can use [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929772/7366707).

Comment: Thanks for this! I forgot the " --> PACKAGENAME.  <-- BlockDirt" when setting the `blockNameConverted` and also changed the other thing to `Block block = clas.getInstance();`